# How to config health-check for ECS with multiple target groups using cdk

Tags: amazon-ecs, health-check, aws-cdk

I'm using cdk to create an ecs service which will expose multiple ports.

Then I'm using `ApplicationMultipleTargetGroupsEc2Service` construct like this:

```
listener_1, listener_2

alb_props = ecs_patterns.ApplicationLoadBalancerProps(
            name="custom-alb-name",
            domain_name="*.example.com",
            domain_zone=route53.HostedZone.from_hosted_zone_attributes(
                self, "HostedZone",
                hosted_zone_id="xxxxxx",
                zone_name="example.com"
            ),
            listeners=[
                listener_1, listener2
            ],
            public_load_balancer=False
        )

target_props_1 = ecs_patterns.ApplicationTargetProps(
            container_port=8001,
            protocol=ecs.Protocol.TCP,
            listener=listener_1.name
        )

target_props_2 = ecs_patterns.ApplicationTargetProps(
            container_port=8444,
            protocol=ecs.Protocol.TCP,
            listener=listener_2.name
        )

ecs_service = ecs_patterns.ApplicationMultipleTargetGroupsEc2Service(
            self, "ECS-ID",
            service_name="service-name",
            cluster=cluster-name-ref,
            task_definition=task_definition,
            load_balancers=[alb_props],
            target_groups=[target_props_1, target_prop_2],
            cpu=1024,
            memory_reservation_mib=2048,
            desired_count=1
        )
```

The default health check for target groups (1 and 2) :

- path: `/`
- code: 200

How can i config the health check of target groups using cdk (I'm using Python but i think it's similar for other languages)

Another problem, I already provided the name of load balancer while creating ecs service (`custom-alb-name`) but this is not working. The load balancer is auto-generated. I'm not sure if i config it right way or this is a bug of the cdk lib

Thank you all guys!!